# Can I use Google authentication with AZ Static Web Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

We have an **Angular** app uses Google's user authentication login. Per [API Integrated security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/apis), believe it means we can use it but not required to. In other words, we still can use non-pre-configured providers outside of AZ Directory, GitHub and Twitter.

For example, we can continue using Angular's `sessionStorage` and `interceptor`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Google authentication with Azure Static web apps. custom Authentication using OpenID is supported. Refer details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-custom?tabs=google)